# Encriptar uma função em Delphi

Tags: delphi

É possível encriptar funções em delphi ? Qualquer tipo de criptografia....exemplo, preciso encriptar essa função:

```
  function REspacos(const str: String): string;
const
  cDouble = ' ';
   cOne = '';
begin
   result:=Str;
   while pos(cDouble,result) > 0 do
      result:=StringReplace(result,cDouble,cOne,[rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Gostaria de encriptar ela para ficar ilegível para o cliente final, mais claro, funcionar normal no delphi.

Comment: Quando você compila fica ilegível para o cliente final. Mas se você quer saber se é possível impedir a descompilação, não, não é possível. Claro que qualquer descompilação não vai resultar em código tão legível quanto o original. Bem, em tese, eu já vi código tão mal escrito, que a descompilação melhorou o código :D. Se não é isto, edite a pergunta e explique melhor o que deseja.

Comment: @bigown, a pergunta está escrito corretamente. Eu preciso ENCRIPTAR a função, acredito que você leu errado, por exemplo usando base64 , eu sei que STRINGS da para encriptar tranquilo, mais e uma função inteira é possível encriptar?

Comment: Primeiro, *base64* não encripta nada, ela codifica. São coisas completamente diferentes com propósitos e resultados diferentes. Segundo, estou lendo o que está escrito. Se você está dizendo que quer encriptar o código fonte da função, aí é só fazer como faz com qualquer *string*, um código fonte é uma *string*. Mas sei lá para que isso serviria. Afinal, o código fonte encriptado não poderia ser usado para compilar nada. Se não é nenhuma destas hipóteses, então você precisa explicar o que quer de outra forma. Repetir o que já foi escrito não ajuda.

Comment: Você vai entregar os fontes pro cliente e não quer que ele veja o que a função faz? Ou você vai entregar o executável e tem medo de engenharia reversa?

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, isso mesmo, vou entregar o fonte para o cliente, e não quero que ele veja algumas funções que eu usei. Se ele abrir o fonte pelo Delphi, vai aparecer o código fonte normal, mas, algumas funções estão encriptadas. E se ele for compilar o projeto, ele tem que ser compilado normalmente mesmo com as funções encriptadas, mesmo que eu criar outra função de DECRYPT não tem problema.

Comment: E como você espera chamar essa função `decrypt` antes de compilar? O código só poderá ser compilado se chamar uma outra aplicação sua? Mesmo que seja isto, ainda assim é possível burlar isto. Se vai fazer isto, o contrato que você tem com o cliente permite que você criptografe estas funções? Caso contrário, não adianta uma solução técnica que trará problemas legais. Mas se pode "proteger" certas funções, então as compile como biblioteca e entregue só a biblioteca destas funções, sem os fontes.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado @bigown pelas dicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta fácil: Você não pode.

---

**Contorno**:

Não quero nem entrar no mérito do porquê, então, para que o compilador *"entenda"* o que foi escrito, o código deve estar legível.

Uma forma de contornar seria criar uma DLL contendo as funções *"escondidas"* e liberá-la junto com os fontes.

Segue forma de fazer retirada [daqui](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/dll_basics.htm):

Vá em `File|New|Other|DLL Wizard`;

Substitua o fonte criado por este:

```
library TestLibrary;

uses SysUtils, Classes, Dialogs;

procedure DllMessage; export;
begin
  ShowMessage('Olá Mundo') ;
end;

exports DllMessage;

begin
end.
```

Crie um novo projeto (para testar), inclua um botão no form (button1) e substitua o fonte pelo seguinte:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes,
  Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

 procedure DllMessage; external 'SimpleMessageDLL.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;
begin
  DllMessage;
end;

end.
```

Ao clicar o botão, o sistema chamará a função criada na DLL. Altere a função pela que precisa e distribua a DLL junto ao fonte informando que esta é necessária.

Comment: também é possível colocar as funções "secretas" em uma unit separada e enviar apenas o arquivo *.dcu